# phpmailer AddAttachment() csv file

Tags: phpmailer

I use AddAttachment with no problem sending zip files, but when I try to send .csv file, everything seems OK, I get a "mail sent" message, but the mail never arrives?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is highly likely that the mail is blocked by the spamfilter on the arriving mail server. You should test and rule that out first.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check the mail server logs on the outgoing mail server used to send the message.  These should tell you 1) whether or not outgoing message received the message from phpmailer, and 2) whether or not the receiving mail server accepted delivery of the message.